# Webstorm string templates using backticks(`)

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, require, webstorm, template-strings

I just upgraded to the last version of WebStorm(11.0).

I have in my code require in that syntax:

```
let path = require(`../../assets/js/templates/${thisTemplate}`);
```

The problem is that WebStorm says:

> Module is not installed

And if I hit the `yellow bulb` I get suggestion:

> Install '`..'

P.S. Before, when I used the older version(10.X-don't remember which exactly), I got no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a result of new Node.js inspection Missing module dependency. Reported an issue that you can follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18919

As a workaround for now please disable that inspection manually by going to Preferences | Editor | Inspections - JavaScript - Node.js - Missing module dependency or hit alt-enter on the highlighted error then hit Arrow right and select Disable inspection.

Comment: 10X-"Missing module dependency: disable for paths using template strings in require" will be fix in WebStorm ver. 11.0.2

Comment: I just install build 143.1183, and it seems that now WebStorm not yields `Module is not installed`, but it's not seems to be recognized to make auto-completion. If I try `let fs = require('fs')`(**with back-ticks**) and I hit `Ctrl+Right-Click` it says: `Can't find declaration to go to` and it's not suggest me auto-completion for the fs module. It's another bug or it's just because it's a EAP version, and it will be fully fix in WebStorm v11.0.2?